# Multiple Transform Filters, Altair

Tags: python, altair

Is there any way in which to get say three charts working together, where a selection on any one of them updates the other?

This only seems possible for two plots, since from what I can see, you can only attach one transform filter.

e.g.

```
brush = alt.selection(type='interval')
nationality_select = alt.selection(type='single', fields=['Nationality'])
club_select = alt.selection(type='single', fields=['Club_Position'])

points = alt.Chart().mark_circle().encode(
x='Acceleration',
y='Speed',
color=alt.condition(brush, 'Nationality:N', alt.value('lightgray')),
tooltip=['Club_Position', 'Name']
).add_selection(
    brush
).transform_filter(
    nationality_select
)

bars_nationality = alt.Chart().mark_bar().encode(
    color='Nationality',
    x='count(Nationality)',
    y=alt.Y('Nationality',
        sort=alt.SortField(field='count', order='descending', op='max')
    )
).properties(
    selection=nationality_select
).transform_filter(
    brush
)

bars_club_position = alt.Chart().mark_bar().encode(
    color='Club_Position',
    x='count(Club_Position)',
    y=alt.Y('Club_Position',
    sort=alt.SortField(field='count', order='descending', op='max')
    )
).properties(
    selection=club_select
).transform_filter(
    brush
)

alt.vconcat(points, bars_nationality, bars_club_position, d 
data=fifa.sample(2000))
```

I can't do this for example

```
.transform_filter(
    brush, nationality_filter
)
```

So is there any way in which to add multiple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add any number of filter transformations to a chart, by calling `transform_filter` multiple times. For example:

```
chart.transform_filter(
    selection1
).transform_filter(
    selection2
)
```

All transformations will be applied in the order that they are added to the chart.

The other possible approach is to use boolean logic to combine multiple selections in a single filter transform; e.g.

```
chart.transform_filter(
    selection1 & selection2
)
```

In your case, this should have the same effect.